# Subtract today's date with date column in SQL

Tags: sql, datediff

I have a column in SQL `item_expired`, this column stores data in the form of dates from other items. What I want to ask, how do I subtract **existing date** in `item_expired` column with the **current date**, which will then be stored in the `remaining_time` column.

I've tried the command below, but isn't working:

```
SELECT
    item_description, item_expired,      
    item_date = DATEDIFF(DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, item_expired) 
FROM Customers;
```

Comment: Date functions are highly vendor specifict, so the answer does depend on the database you are running. Please tag your question with this information: are you using MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GMB has mentioned in the comment above, date functions depend on the database type you are using. Assuming you are asking about MySQL the below query will provide you with the remaining time required.

```
select 
    (CURRENT_DATE - item_expired) as remaining_time 
from customers;
```

While this will provide you with the remaining time, you will have to write a separate insert to insert the remaining time for the table column.

Answer (score 0):

Query in sql server :

```
select DATEDIFF(day, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,item_expired)
```

will give you the difference in days between the current date and the item_expired date

Provide more information about you problef for more direct answers